# Choosing Backend for Multilingual E-commerce with Nuxt 3, MongoDB, GraphQL

Tags: vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js, e-commerce, apollo

I'm building a multilingual e-commerce website using Nuxt 3 for the frontend, probably MongoDB for the database, and GraphQL for the API.
But I'm not well experienced in backend...
So I'm looking for recommendations on the best backend technologies or headless CMS to use for this project. Ideally, the solution should be scalable, secure, and customizable.

Here are my considerations:

- Nitro: A build in choice with Nuxt3 has cross-platform support for Node.js, browsers, service-workers and more, serverless support out-of-the-box, API routes support, automatic code-splitting and async-loaded chunks, hybrid mode for static + serverless sites, development server with hot module reloading.
- Express.js: A popular choice with Nuxt.js due to its simplicity and seamless integration. It's known for being fast and lightweight.
- Strapi: A headless CMS great for managing content for websites and applications. Provides a user-friendly interface for creating content models, managing users, and exposing data through a GraphQL API.
- Storefront
- Nestjs

If you have better ideas, I'd love to know them